# Telling Jest to not mock /moment(-timezone)?/ not working

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

Getting an error with jest where anytime moment/moment.tz() is called, `TypeError: (0 , _moment2.default)(...).tz is not a function` is thrown. Below is my jest config with absolute paths redacted.

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "<absolute path>",
      "clearMocks": true,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "globals": {
        "window": true
      },
      "haste": {
        "providesModuleNodeModules": []
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules",
        "src"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "vue"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": [
        [
          "^@/(.*)$",
          "/<absolute path>/src/$1"
        ],
        [
          "\\.(css|less)$",
          "/<absolute path>/test/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
        ]
      ],
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "79986797be68f3008e950f2cefe0bbd1",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "rootDir": "<absolute path>",
      "roots": [
        "<absolute path>/src",
        "<absolute path>/test"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "snapshotSerializers": [
        "/<absolute path>/node_modules/jest-serializer-html/index.js"
      ],
      "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom",
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.js?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)(spec|test).js?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/",
        "test/e2e/"
      ],
      "testRegex": "",
      "testRunner": "/<absolute path>/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "about:blank",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          ".*\\.(vue)$",
          "/<absolute path>/node_modules/vue-jest/vue-jest.js"
        ],
        [
          ".*\\.js$",
          "/opt/cm/cm_frontend/cm/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
        "moment",
        "moment-timezone"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": false,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/components/**/*.{js,vue}",
      "src/mixins/**/*.js",
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<ABSOLUTE PATH>",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "expand": false,
    "listTests": false,
    "mapCoverage": true,
    "maxWorkers": 7,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "rootDir": "<ROOT PATH HERE>",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": false,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "21.2.1"
}
```

I've tried telling jest to `jest.dontMock()` as well as `jest.unmock()` but to no avail.

I've also tried `require.requireActual()`.

I want to only mock moment when I specify per test (per file) with `jest.mock()`.

What could be causing these issues? I am not mocking or unmocking moment anywhere in my test files. I've just simply used `@vue/test-utils` to mock entire computed properties using moment to get around this issue in the meantime.

Comment: Can't check locally rn, but how are you importing moment in the tests?

Comment: @LuisOrduz I am pretty sure I have tried this but no, I’m not currently importing it. Is this the standard way to do so?

Comment: Why don't you try importing it and see what happens?

Comment: @LuisOrduz I will. But this may be due to missing something fundamental. I thought I wouldn’t need to import it in my test since my source imports it, and I’m not using moment in the test, I will try when I get to my computer. Thanks

Comment: @LuisOrduz You can officially answer so I can award the bounty. Silly me.

Comment: Wait, did just importing them directly work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try importing them directly in the tests. Also, I checked issues and other questions and it seems that importing `timezone` doesn't actually add the `tz` function to `moment`, so a way to solve it could be:

```
import moment from "moment-timezone"
```

Comment: This finally solved it for me, thanks. What I needed to do was to first import this, then mocking moment as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68250465/251961