# Jest mock moment() to return specific date

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, momentjs

I know this question has been asked multiple times.

But I could not find the correct one for my case.

I would like to mock the moment() to return a specific date.

**First**, I mock by

```
jest.mock("moment", () => {
  return (date: string) =>
    jest.requireActual("moment")(date || "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
});
```

But I use some properties of moment, (`moment.duration()...` for example) So when mock like this, it does not work.

**Next** I tried to mock `Date.now` by several ways:

```
jest.spyOn(Date, "now").mockReturnValue(+new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"));
```

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => +new Date("2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")
```

But when doing this, when calling `moment()` it returns an invalid date.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: See if [How to mock moment.utc() for unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46891897/4131048) and linked questions can be useful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Mock the `moment()` function and its returned value. Use `jest.requireActual('moment')` to get the original module. Copy its properties and methods to the mocked one.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
import moment from 'moment';

export function main() {
  const date = moment().format();
  console.log('date: ', date);
  const duration = moment.duration(2, 'minutes').humanize();
  console.log('duration: ', duration);
}
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
import { main } from '.';
import moment from 'moment';

jest.mock('moment', () => {
  const oMoment = jest.requireActual('moment');
  const mm = {
    format: jest.fn(),
  };
  const mMoment = jest.fn(() => mm);
  for (let prop in oMoment) {
    mMoment[prop] = oMoment[prop];
  }
  return mMoment;
});

describe('68209029', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    moment().format.mockReturnValueOnce('2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
    main();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68209029/index.test.js (8.914 s)
  68209029
    ✓ should pass (20 ms)

  console.log
    date:  2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

      at Object.main (examples/68209029/index.js:5:11)

  console.log
    duration:  2 minutes

      at Object.main (examples/68209029/index.js:7:11)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.726 s
```

Take a look at the logs, we mocked the returned value of `moment().format()` correctly and keep using the original implementation of `moment.duration(2, 'minutes').humanize()` method.

Comment: Good idea. I actually wanted to mock the `moment()` not the `format`

But based on your answer, I could figure it out how to do it.

By mocking like this:

```
jest.mock("moment", () => {
  const oMoment = jest.requireActual("moment");
  const mMoment: any = (date: string | undefined) =>
    oMoment(date || "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");
  for (let prop in oMoment) {
    mMoment[prop] = oMoment[prop];
  }
  return mMoment;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Additional to @slideshowp2's answer.

Just wanted to add another way for this:

```js
jest.mock("moment", () => {
  // Require actual moment
  const actualMoment = jest.requireActual("moment");

  // Mocking moment func: 
  // moment() => return specific date, and it won't affect moment(date) with param.
  const mockMoment: any = (date: string | undefined) =>
    actualMoment(date || "2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z");

  // Now assign all properties from actual moment to the mock moment, so that they can be used normally
  for (let prop in actualMoment) {
    mockMoment[prop] = actualMoment[prop];
  }
  return mockMoment;
});
```

Comment: oMoment doesn't exist in your snippet

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this too

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
    const originalModule = jest.requireActual('moment')

    return {
        __esModule: true,
        ...originalModule,
        default: () => originalModule('2023-06-23')
    }
})
```

I try it on jest v29.3